# Implementar kafka sobre un proyecto de .NET web form?

Tags: .net, hilos, webforms, kafka

Me gustaría saber si es posible implementar una capa que maneje apache kafka sobre un proyecto de .NET web forms, ya que debo conectar un proyecto construido con ASP.NET core que ya cuenta con su implementación de kafka con otro un poco más antiguo desarrollado web form con framework net 4.0.

De momento tengo una capa aparte donde implemento la librería Confluent.Kafka en la cual he generado la clase del consumidor y del productor

Productor:

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using System;


namespace PublishAndSubscribe.Impl
{
    public class KafkaProducer
    {
        private readonly ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig{ BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092" };
        private Object SendToKafka(string topic, string message)
        {

            using (var producer =
                 new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build())
            {
                try
                {
                    return producer.ProduceAsync(topic, new Message<Null, string> { Value = message })
                        .GetAwaiter()
                        .GetResult();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"something went wrong: {e}");
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace PublishAndSubscribe
{
    public class KafkaConsumer : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly string topic = "topic";
        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var conf = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = "st_consumer_group",
                BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };
            using (var builder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore,
                string>(conf).Build())
            {
                builder.Subscribe(topic);
                var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var consumer = builder.Consume(cancelToken.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Message: {consumer.Message.Value} received from {consumer.TopicPartitionOffset}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    builder.Close();
                }
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Mi problema principal es que no sé cómo mantener la ejecución del consumer en un hilo aparte desde el proyecto de web form ya que en construido con net core lo manejo desde el archivo Program.cs iniciando un servicio con la ejecucion del proyecto

Espero me puedan orientar un poco ya que no manejo muy bien webforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno lo que finalmente hice fue levantar un hilo desde el global.asax de la siguiente manera y funciona, no es la mejor implementación pero como base funciona

```
var sendMessage = new Thread(() => {
    CancellationToken cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationToken();
    var client = new PublishAndSubscribe.KafkaConsumer();
    client.StartAsync(cancellationTokenSource);
});
sendMessage.Start();
```